# Querying Firebase, Retrieving, And Passing To Adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get values from firebase. Here, I'm not able to get the values inside the "attendance" node.

[image]

Here is my model:

```
public class MemberInGroup {

private String name;
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> attendance;
private String group;

public MemberInGroup() {

}

public MemberInGroup(String name, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> attendance, String group) {
    this.name = name;
    this.attendance = attendance;
    this.group = group;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getGroup() {
    return group;
}

public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> getAttendance() {
    return attendance;
}
```

Here is the populateView method in the adapter:

```
    @Override
protected void populateView(View view, MemberInGroup member, int i) {

    final String name = member.getName();
    final String group = member.getGroup();

    // Create views and assign values
    final TextView nameTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTxtView);
    nameTxtView.setText(name);

    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> attendance = member.getAttendance();

    if(attendance != null) {
        HashMap<String, Object>  todayAttendance = attendance.get(Utility.getTodayName());
        if(todayAttendance != null) {

            String date = (String) todayAttendance.get("date");
        } 
    }
```

I'm able to retrieve "name" and "group" values, but not the day hash map inside the "attendance". Utility.getTodayName gives the correct day name, but "date" returns null.

Here is how I query the database and set the adapter:

```
                    final DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();

                Query query = ref.child("members")
                        .orderByChild("group")
                        .equalTo("group7");

                // Set the adapter with groupMembersRef
                MembersOfGroupAdapter mOfGroupAdapter = new MembersOfGroupAdapter(getActivity(), MemberInGroup.class,
                        R.layout.list_item_member_in_sport, query);
                sportMembersListView.setAdapter(mOfGroupAdapter);
```

I'm trying to query all members who are in certain group. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Utility.getTodayName gives the correct day name, but "date" returns null.

You have an intermediate key between the day name and the date value. You need to go through that. In other words, that's the string value that you must `get()` before have access to the inner object that contains `date` key.

By the way, you should be using `TreeMap`, not `Hashmap` if you expect to iterate any values in order.

You could simply use a for loop over the keySet of that map where you currently use `get("date")` to loop over all keys, use `get(key).get("date")`.

---

The thing about NoSQL is that there's multiple approaches to do what you want, but perhaps you should think about remodeling your data to add an attendance node at the same level of members. There's no reason to place everything under the members key, and sometimes duplicating information is necessary to achieve some type of JOIN like in SQL.

I'll assume a similar model to what you have

```
attendance 
    monday
        member::1
    tuesday
        member::1
        member::2
members 
    member::1
        name 
        email
    member::2
groups
    group::7
        members
            member::4
```

So then, you have two query paths that'll be easier to access, depending on the data you want. For example, all the members, all the groups, the attendees for one day of the week, etc.

With my suggestion here, you would have to do more than one lookup against the database. Once to get all members, then additional ones to get the attendance and groups, then filter out for a given member.

You'd probably do that within the adapter getView method where you'd have access to a member. it'd be something like `ref('attendance').child(day)`, and then you'd need to check the children of that and `startAt(memberId).endAt(memberId)`, I think, to get the one member key. And if there is any data returned there, that Hashmap you'd `get(memberId).get('date')`.

The requirements being that you not use randomly generated keys for your members, hence the `object::<id>` notation.

Comment: You're right that's why date was null. If I remodel the database, how would I pass the result to the adapter?  Because in populateView I use the model class to get the attendance. Is it possible to make a new query inside the populateView?

Comment: and how that get() will get called

Comment: I've added more to my answer, but, yes, it should be possible to do another query in the populateView method. It won't look nice in the code with the nested listeners, of course